# How to deal with multiple fetch requests that are the same?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, asynchronous, fetch

Let's say that I have multiple `eventListeners` and some of the use the same fetch request. Is there a way I can avoid writing multiple fetch requests that get the same data?

```
async function foo(){
    let request = await fetch(foo.com/data)
    let response = await request.json()
}

async function foo2(){
    let request = await fetch(foo.com/data)
    let response = await request.json()
}
```

Comment: Cache the results in a global variable. Then check if the variable is set before making another fetch request.

Comment: Could you provide an example? @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Cache the response in a global variable, and check the variable before fetching again.

```js
let foo_data;

async function foo() {
  let response;
  if (foo_data === undefined) {
    let request = await fetch('foo.com/data')
    response = await request.json()
    foo_data = response;
  } else {
    response = foo_data;
  }
}

async function foo2() {
  let response;
  if (foo_data === undefined) {
    let request = await fetch('foo.com/data')
    response = await request.json()
  } else {
    response = foo_data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Barmar's answer is good for if the second request comes in after the first request is made, but consider this alternative approach to support two `fetch` requests made at nearly the same time, which would only actually trigger one real fetch request:

You have an object where each key is a url, and the values are the Promises returned by `fetch(url)`. You have some kind of controller class which, when a fetch request comes in, checks if there's already a Promise available for that url. If there is, it gives you back that promise. If there isn't, it makes one and stores it:

```
const cachedPromises = {};

class CachedPromiseController {
    static fetch(url) {
        if (cachedPromises[url]) return cachedPromises[url];
        return CachedPromiseController.newFetch(url);
    }

    static newFetch(url) {
        const promise = fetch(url);
        cachedPromises[url] = promise;
        // maybe you want to delete the cached promise after 30 seconds, so you don't have stale data?
        promise
            .then(async r => {
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000 * 30)); // wait for 30 seconds
                delete cachedPromises[url];
            })
            .catch(e => {
                // delete it immediately if it's an error
                delete cachedPromises[url];
                throw e; // we have to throw this or the consumer won't know there was an error
            })

        return promise;
    }
}
```

That's a very rough and entirely untested implementation, but it's how i imagined it in my head.